# Кодировка на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, .htaccess, кодировка

Здравствуйте, уже сколько мучаюсь, но никак не могу найти полного ответа на этот вопрос.

1. Какая кодировка должна быть в базе данных (MySQL, если используется русский, казахский и английский язык), и нужно ли прописывать настройки в .htacces и что писать точно?
2. Какая кодировка в html странице и как правильно ее там прописать для всех случаев?
3. В пхп файле?
4. В пхп при создание xml файлов?
5. Нужно ли в JavaScript прописывать кодировку, в CSS?

Изучаю языки веб программирования уже вроде как год, а каждый, раз выкладывая работы на сервер, проблема с языком. )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Полностью:

-- mysql: везде указывать кодировку UTF8 и сравнение(collation) utf8_general_ci

-- php:

1) после подключения к БД

```
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8;');
```

2) по желанию добавить перед выводом

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf8');
```

-- ide(редакторы): проверять кодировку, чтоб была юникодом. Желательно ее поставить по умолчанию.

-- apache: в файл .htaccess дописать строку

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF8
```

-- html: в <head></head> добавить тег

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf8" />
```

Comment: не знаю на сколько сильно я гоню, вот скрин (http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=37a44b9ab67095dda9efa339a270bcbb)  в IE opera chrome везде не отображает! стоит Denwer последний, если что скажите сделаю еще скрины или скину сам код)) очень благодарен!!!

Comment: а кажется это проблема с денвером, создал файл все как вы сказали и запустил его с рабочего стола, все было отлично, а когда в папку сервера закинул, и запустил через localhost/ то были каракули ужасные!

Answer (score 1):

В css и js ничего не нужно писать. Делайте везде utf8. В php добавьте после подключения к БД:

```
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
```

В бд таблица и поля utf8. В хедере пишите

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: >В бд таблица и поля utf8.

БД И таблицы в UTF8 :)

Comment: я поставил кодировку ютф8, теперь все надписи превратились в               Р’С‹Р±РѕСЂРєР° Р”Р°РЅРЅС‹С… РёР· Р‘Р”

Comment: пропишите в .htacces : AddDefaultCharset utf-8

Comment: прописал, безрезультатно) http://saveimg.ru/show-image.php?id=65d2b24f501d6d70d60e47dd2db31416

Comment: причем в Dreamweaver отображает нормлаьно все символы))

Comment: Если у тебя не CMS и не CMF - файл сделай utf8, а не ANSII

Answer (score 0):

А в каком браузере открываете? Может там задано принудительно?
в скрипте вместо mysql_set_charset('utf8'); можно попробовать
mysql_query ("set character_set_client='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set character_set_results='utf8'");
mysql_query ("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");

вроде так...я делал для cp1251 именно так.

Кстати рекомендую использовать редактор PHP Expert Editor (для русских регистрация бесплатна по мылу)

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8");
это пишешь в php файлы, и русский с английским тебе обеспечны

Answer (score 0):

если используешь кодировку utf8 то кодировка php, html файлов должна быть utf8

Answer (score -1):

попробуй открыть страничку,
и если там будет кодеровка не правильная.. = потестируй с кодеровкой (по переключайте её в браузере)
в ie это меню > вид > кодеровка.
в mozilla fx или там же.
и вот какая пойдёт - такую и ставь..