# Выбор правильной кодировки или utf-8 vs windows-1251?

Tags: кодировка, javascript, html, php

Здравствуйте уважаемые!
Вот уже второй день меня мучает вопрос про кодировки.

Какую же кодировку использовать при разработке `html`, `javascript`, `css` и в **особенности PHP** скриптов одновременно на ОС `Win 7` и `Linux`?
Для корректного отображение их в таких обозревателей как: `Chrome` и `Firefox`, без необходимости постоянной настройки кодировки?

Дело в том, что при установки кодировки `UTF-8` по умолчанию в `phpStorm` и `phpDesigner`, `Firefox` выдает, извините, "дребедень" и постоянная смена настоек обозревателя не очень то и радует. При использовании `windows-1251` не уверен в корректности отображения ее на `linux`, но это я к слову.

Так вот `UTF-8` или `windows-1251`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UTF-8 однозначно, кодировка намного более емкая, нет проблем с другими языками и т.п.

Судя по всему, у вас нет соответствующих заголовков, потому смотрите мой ответ [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/26814/%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B5)

Comment: Почему однозначно? Есть и огромные (ВКонтакте) и малые проекты, использующие cp-1251.

Comment: Ну скажем так, я в свое время настрадался из-за этого, + большинство того, что можно скачать в инете - в UTF-8 + банально в нем есть спецсимволы. Опять же, для несколькоязычного проекта это важно, чтоб какой-нибудь немецкий-французский не обрабатывать отдельно.
Upd: ради прикола посмотрел вк - туреский он отображает через html-entity, `&#NNNN;`, не думаю, что это хороший способ)

Comment: Спасибо за подробное разъяснение,пожалуй перейду на utf-8.